# AmpScript issue with IF Statement

Tags: ampscript

I am trying to do a lookup to two different data extensions in exact target using ampscript. Please find the sample code I am trying .

```
%%[
Var @rows
Set @rows=LookupRows("DataExtensionOne","Lead Owner","Nick")
FOR @y = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO 
    Set @currentRow = Row(@rows,@y)    
    Set @value = FIELD(@currentRow ,"LeadId")
    Set @secondDERows = LookupRows("DataExtensionTwo","Gender","Male")
    FOR @x = 1 TO RowCount(@secondDERows) DO 
        Set @currentRowInSecDE = Row(@secondDERows,@x)    
        Set @secValue = FIELD(@currentRowInSecDE ,"LeadId")
        IF @value == @secValue THEN
            Set @FirstName = FIELD(@currentRowInSecDE ,"FirstName")
        /* Need to break out of the loop */
]%%
```

The If condition check seems to fail @value == @secValue .
It doesnt fetch any value for the @FirstName. And what statement should be used to break out of IF loop ?

Has anyone come across similar problems ? Please do let me know.

Comment: Missing an endif at end.

Comment: Can you post all of the script?  None of your loops are closed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, ampscript does not have a break operator.

In this case, I would set up a boolean value that is checked to be false at the start of each loop and is set to True when you find a match.  This way once you have matched you'll still run through the rest of the loop but noting will happen within them.

```
%%[
Var @rows
Set @found_result = False
Set @rows=LookupRows("DataExtensionOne","Lead Owner","Nick")
FOR @y = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO
    if not @found_result then
        Set @currentRow = Row(@rows,@y)    
        Set @value = FIELD(@currentRow ,"LeadId")
        Set @secondDERows = LookupRows("DataExtensionTwo","Gender","Male")
        FOR @x = 1 TO RowCount(@secondDERows) DO 
            if not @found_result then
                Set @currentRowInSecDE = Row(@secondDERows,@x)    
                Set @secValue = FIELD(@currentRowInSecDE ,"LeadId")
                IF @value == @secValue THEN
                    Set @FirstName = FIELD(@currentRowInSecDE ,"FirstName")
                    Set @found_result = True
                ENDIF
            endif
        NEXT @x
    endif
NEXT @y
]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%%[
Var @rows
Set @found_result = False
Set @rows=LookupRows("DataExtensionOne","Lead Owner","Nick")
    FOR @y = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO
    if  @found_result == "TRUE" then
        Set @currentRow = Row(@rows,@y)    
        Set @value = FIELD(@currentRow ,"LeadId")

Set @secondDERows = LookupRows("DataExtensionTwo","Gender","Male")

        FOR @x = 1 TO RowCount(@secondDERows) DO 
            if @found_result == "TRUE" then
                Set @currentRowInSecDE = Row(@secondDERows,@x)    
                Set @secValue = FIELD(@currentRowInSecDE ,"LeadId")
                IF @value == @secValue THEN
                    Set @FirstName = FIELD(@currentRowInSecDE ,"FirstName")
                    Set @found_result = True
                ENDIF
            endif
        NEXT @x
    endif
NEXT @y
]%%
```